# What is the defect in the standard model with quark interactions

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, axion

I am watching the Master Class Axions: Ghost Riders in the Sky as well as another lecture, this one given by Michael Turner.  In his lecture, he states the Axion idea came about because of a defect in the standard model concerning how quarks interact.  But I cannot find what this defect is.  Can someone explain this defect  in layman's terms?  I am not a scientist.

Thanks

Comment: The absence of observable strong CP violation is a highly technical mathematical phenomenon, and I doubt a  nonmathematical description could do justice to it at any level.

Comment: maybe reading this and the next paragrapj will help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axion#Strong_CP_problem